# "bubbles" forming after heating my Thin film transistors

Tags: materials, thin-films

I am fabricating **Bottom gate Thin-film-Transistors**.

The **Gate** is 60nm Molibdenum. The **dielectric** structure changes with the table below. The temperature represent the annealing temperature after having deposited the IGZO **semiconductor**.

```
sample  Structure temperature
1       SiTa      300
2       SiTa      180
3       SiTaSi    300
4       SiTaSi    180
5       TaSi      300
6       TaSi      180
```

after heating the samples, I am getting these bubble-like formation on the gate structure.

what could be causing this issue? 
Prebake SiTa-300

[image: prebake]
Postbake SiTa-300
[image: Postbake]

Prebake SiTa-180
[image: Prebake]
Postbake SiTa-180
[image: Postbake]

prebake SiTaSi-300
[image: prebake]
postbake SiTaSi-300
[image: Postbake]

Prebake SiTaSi-180
[image: Prebake]
Postbake SiTaSi-180
[image: Posbake]